# Disable background on desktop Excel using office js displayDialogAsync function

Tags: javascript, office365, ms-office, office-js

We are using add-in manifest file to run application on taskpane on Desktop office 365.
We have use **office js** **DisplayDialogAsync** function to open dialog box i.e.

**Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync('https://myDomain/myDialog.html', {height: 30, width: 20, displayInIframe: true}).**

Dialog box get open and close also but we want to restrict user by clicking on background of Excel on Desktop.
Please do let me know if anything is helpful to me. Our production is getting effected by lack of this functionality.

Comment: I don't see any Teams related issue here?

Answer (score 0):

The dialog that is created by the `displayDialogAsync` method is non-modal. Perhaps as a workaround, you could set the height and width to 100. This should cause the dialog to fill most of the screen, although it won't prevent users from moving dialog and clicking on other things. But having a modal option to the dialog is a good idea. Please request it at [Office Developer Suggestion Box](https://office365.uservoice.com/).